# dialogPostRun method in RunBaseReport

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a **RunBaseReport** which contains overrided dialog method where I'm adding couple of my controls. One of those controls is a combobox. 
Controls *enabled()* property should be changed when I'm modifying combobox.

So basically I need to know when the value of my **dfReportType** dialog field changes.

```
public Object dialog(Object dialog)
{
     DialogRunbase dialog = dialog;
     ;
     //adding my combobox
     dfReportType = dialog.addFieldValue(typeid(ReportType), ReportType:DefaultType);
     //adding some other controls here
     return dialog; 
}
```

According to many articles that I found I need to override **dialogPostRun** Method and do something like this:

```
public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase dialog)
{
    super(dialog);
    dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverload(true);
    dialog.dialogForm().formRun().controlMethodOverloadObject(this);
}
```

But unfortunately I don't have this method in **RunBaseReport** class. 
Which should be there according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa630017(v=ax.50).aspx) .

Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no **dialogPostRun** method in **Report** object that inherits RunBaseReport, but we have this method in **Class** that inherits RunBaseReport.

So that was my mistake. I used report object instead of class.

If you want to make custom dialog for the report but you also want to use all default controls you should:

- Create class
- Inherit RunBaseReport
- Override dialog, getFromDialog etc.
- Override lastValueElementName method

  ```
  public identifiername lastValueElementName()
  {
      //just put name of your report object
      return reportStr(YourReportName);
  }
  ```

Don't forget to add **main()** method if you going to make call from menuItem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently on AX 2012 but I still looked at it. I have the method available in the context menu, but not on the first column. I have to go over "Plus..." to find the method in the second column.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that "Plus" in AX 2009.

Comment: I've switched to EN-US. Then, in 'Override method', at the bottom, there is a 'More...' option with an Arrow which will open the next column.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. I tried to override it on **report** that inhertis RunBaseReport class and that was a mistake, I had to use **class** object instead. But thanks' anyway.